# Jupyter Notebook does not change text color ! termcolor ore colorama on windows 10

Tags: python

I first started to understand Python. I saw the lessons on YouTube. And installed as in the video - Anaconda Navigator (anaconda3). Used Jupyter Notebook.
Then I started writing code. And I ran into a problem. The color of the text does not change as it does in the video. I don’t understand what is the problem? please tell me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuHVk.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKTC2.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISLlX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

everything worked as soon as I changed the laptop theme to dark.
jt -t chesterish

it is not clear why it does not work in the standard program

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f875i.jpg)